# MySQL query causes "user already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

When I run this query:

```
SELECT 
        (SELECT MAX(`newsm`.`id`))  AS `news_id`,
        (SELECT MAX(`articlesm`.`id`))  AS `articles_id`,
        (SELECT MAX(`albumsm`.`id`))  AS `albums_id`,
        (SELECT MAX(`videosm`.`id`))  AS `videos_id`
FROM `newsm`, `articlesm`, `albumsm`, `videosm`;
```

it runs okay on my localhost, but when i run it on my website it opens too many threads and causes the website to go down due to max_user_connections error.

I check the number of threads by this line
`echo $pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_INFO);` before running the query, the number of threads are 2, after running the query, the number increases infinitely till the website go down and show error 503.

Comment: Bad? I don't know. What's the point of this query?

Comment: How can a single query open "too many threads" and cause the website to go down? As far as I know the website will just patiently wait for MySQL to return the result, it won't open new threads and won't go down because of what MySQL is doing.

Comment: @Strawberry I want to get the latest id from these 4 tables.

Comment: @apokryfos I check the number of threads by this line `echo $pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_INFO);` before running the query, the number of threads are 2, after running the query, the number increases infinitely till the website go down and show error 503.

Comment: But why? How's that useful?

Comment: Although this query is kind of bizarre, it should run quickly if each table has `id` set as a `PRIMARY KEY`. What data are you getting back that refers to threads?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question depends on what your meaning of the word "bad" is.  If doing a cross join between 4 tables, each of which could be very large, when such a join is unnecessary, then yes your query is bad.  If all you want are max values from each of the 4 separate tables, then you don't really need the cross join, because the max values coming from columns associated with individual tables won't be changed by the join.  Instead, try the following query:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(`newsm`.`id`) FROM `newsm`)  AS `news_id`,
       (SELECT MAX(`articlesm`.`id`) FROM `articlesm`)  AS `articles_id`,
       (SELECT MAX(`albumsm`.`id`) FROM `albumsm`)  AS `albums_id`,
       (SELECT MAX(`videosm`.`id`) FROM `vidoesm`)  AS `videos_id`
```

Comment: Thank you. But can you help me with this: `Uptime: 40405 Threads: 527 Questions: 1344285 Slow queries: 4 Opens: 10600 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 2449 Queries per second avg: 33.270` How can I stop these threads, because the db became too slow.

Comment: I'd expect there to be a large penalty for an unnecessary 4-way Cartesian product; the query will return W * X * Y * Z (where those numbers indicate the row counts of the respective tables) results, and depending on how smart MySQL is feeling may calculate MAX values (for the subqueries) on each table that many times as well. _At very least it will calculate the max values once and then duplicate them that many times; and MAYBE it will be smart enough to not actually go through with the JOIN, and just duplicate the max values directly._